# What is your company's budget for computers used for software development?

Tags: laptop, desktop

It would be very helpful if you could share this, because I'm trying to convince my boss that my company's budget is not adequate, but I can't find any relevant data anywhere to prove my point.

If you can, please specify if computers are desktop or laptop and the renewal rate of the hardware. The size of the company would also be interesting to know.

I'm grateful for any response.

Comment: This question is too broad, too opinion based, and really not about a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, pricing is one of the least important things to check for a company.

What is more important, and what can influence your manager much better, is to write down, what it SAVES when you have faster/better computers.

Example: Assume to compiler a full build takes 30 minutes on a slow computer and 10 minutes on a fast computer. This saves the developer approximately 10 minutes (assuming he cannot do much useful stuff in the mean time). Assuming a salary of 50 dollars/hr, saving ten minutes  saves 50 * (20/60) = 16.67 dollars.

Assume you do 10 builds per week, it saves 167 dollar per week. 
When the faster computer cost 1000 dollars more, after 1000/167 = 6 weeks, the computer is paid back.

The complication is that sometimes it's hard to calculate (what if your manager says you can do something useful in the waiting time? Probably you have context switching time loss etc).

But in general, if the faster computer can saves you considerable time, the salary losses  outweighs the cost of a computer by far.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this type of reasoning with my boss, but it doesn't bite. What surprises is that my salary is quite high, but when it comes to hardware, they're trying to keep down costs. It's surprising since the hardware cost is just a couple of thousandths of the salary cost.
However, my boss likes stats, maybe because that's what we work with. So that's why I'm asking for hardcore data.

Comment: I had the same problem with my company too long time ago (but I could give them some good reasons we need better monitors for example). Try to write down as much as 'hard'  data as you can (performance gain, minimum RAM memory needed, minimum SSD or harddisk space needed etc).

Comment: I think asking for hardcore data wouldn't even help much; it depends on what needs the developer have... if you are making an application that can build in 3 seconds, a 3000 dollar computer wouldn't gain much.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. And at the end of that list I will put down how much time I spent doing it :)

Comment: Yes also a good point ... sorry for not having a more positive answer.

Comment: I did what you suggested. I benchmarked my home computer running a 8700K cpu and my computer with a 6700 cpu at work. I calculated all compilations I did every day, took the time difference and multiplied by my hourly cost. For 3 years, which is the time that we have each computer, the cost was almost $4000 USD for the extra time needed by the slower cpu. 
I presented this to my boss, but he still refused to acknowledge the benefits of upgrading. So I left the office and said that this was unacceptable. Later that day he got back to me with an email saying that I would get my desired upgrade.